# How do I shuffle the labels "Patriots" and "Colts" in the "Team" column? (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Assuming this is the Data, how do I shuffle the labels "Patriots" and "Colts" in the "Team" column and append it to a new column?

```
Team  Blakeman  Prioleau    Combined    Pressure Drop
 0  Patriots    11.50   11.80   11.650  0.850
 1  Patriots    10.85   11.20   11.025  1.475
 2  Patriots    11.15   11.50   11.325  1.175
 3  Patriots    10.70   11.00   10.850  1.650
 4  Patriots    11.10   11.45   11.275  1.225
 5  Patriots    11.60   11.95   11.775  0.725
 6  Patriots    11.85   12.30   12.075  0.425
 7  Patriots    11.10   11.55   11.325  1.175
 8  Patriots    10.95   11.35   11.150  1.350
 9  Patriots    10.50   10.90   10.700  1.800
10  Patriots    10.90   11.35   11.125  1.375
11   Colts      12.70   12.35   12.525  0.475
12   Colts      12.75   12.30   12.525  0.475
13   Colts      12.50   12.95   12.725  0.275
14   Colts      12.55   12.15   12.350  0.650
```

Comment: It could have been better if you could have posted a minimal working solution, showing efforts you have taken in finding solution so that you can be helped out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Team': ['Patriots','Patriots','Colts'], 'Blakeman':[11.50,10.85,12.70]})
df['new_col'] = np.random.permutation(df['Team'].values)
df
    Team      Blakeman  new_col
0   Patriots  11.50     Colts
1   Patriots  10.85     Patriots
2   Colts     12.70     Patriots
```